# If not search result submit search term in form

Tags: php, search, conditional-statements

I want to submit search term ( e.g what does foo means) into form if there is not result

Details:

I have a search function with if else condition where if there is search result than display else message with "No search result found"

Where I wan to change "No search result found" with one form submission where value will be whatever search term user try to find. so...

```
if search result found {
 //display result
} else {
  // auto submit below form if above condition is not true ( means if no search result found )

    <form action="to url" method="post">
    <input name="title" type="text" />
    </form>
}
```

Above is the form which I use to submit form.

**EDIT:**

Here is the actual code

```
.......

if (count($results))
            $qa_content['title']=qa_lang_html_sub('main/results_for_x', qa_html($inquery));
        else { ?>

            <form id="nosearch" method="POST" action="<?php echo qa_opt('site_url'); ?>ask" class="top-askbox" >
                    <input name="title" type="text" value="<?php echo $inquery; ?>">
            </form>
            <script>$("#nosearch").submit();</script>

        <?php }

.......
```

this is the part where I am working. Actual file is too long.

Comment: what is the question ? or problem you have ?

Comment: How can I auto submit the form if no search result with search term as a value

Comment: Okay will it work in between php search function code?

Comment: This question is kind of hard to read so please verify this: All you want is for the form to auto fill the last search term the user entered? So if I enter "cool things" in your box and there are no results you just want the form to have "cool things" in the search bar by default, right?

Comment: no if there is no result for "cool things" than it will automatically submit form with "cool things" term.

Comment: Yeppy.. I have done... it is completely fine and working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
 if (is in search ) {
 //display result
} else {
  // auto submit below form if above condition is not true ( means if no search result found )

    <form action="to url" id="main" method="post">
    <input name="title" type="text" value="$value" />
    </form>
<script>$("#main").submit();</script>

}
```

Comment: assuming they're using jquery... but why not just use curl? Why even bother with a front end hack?

Comment: I tried above code but it is outputting text field with value not submitting. Any idea?

Comment: @pixelngrain can you show some code? or have you included juqery or ready function?

Comment: Okay wait I am posting entire code on my question give me a moment please

Comment: Its done with jquery `document.main.submit()`. Thanks a lot for your help and selected your answer and voted..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try this again. My arguement is that it is ridiculous to have the front end auto post a form when you can easily handle that in php...

```
if (count($results))
    $qa_content['title']=qa_lang_html_sub('main/results_for_x', qa_html($inquery));
else { 
    $url = 'http://whatever.com/your-search-file.php';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($results)
    {
        //echo results or do whatever
    }
    else
    {
        // your auto post failed. deal with it
    }
}
```

Assuming cUrl is an option for you. If not, then go with the jquery option others have mentioned.

Comment: Let me try this mean while you can see my edit with actual code I am working... `$inquery` is the variable to get search tearm

Comment: it is also not submitting but it is rendering text element with search term